# motive of the general linear group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives

Let $k$ be a perfect field. Let $GL_n$ be the general linear group over $k$. Does anybody know a reference for the computation of the motive
$$
M(GL_n)
$$ in Voevodsky's category $DM(k)$?

Answer (score 5):

The motive of a split reductive group over a perfect field has been computed by Shahram Biglari in: Motives of reductive groups. Amer. J. Math. 134 (2012), pp.235--257.